# Python prediction of time series

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, prediction

Good evening!
I´m trying to predict glucose level using time series but my LSTM model is not working properly.
Every time I get a different warning. This time  `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported numpy type: NPY_DATETIME).`

I think that I´m not preprocessing the data properly.
What do you think?

`[![This is a sample of the dataset][1]][1]`

My model has been buit in this way

````
model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',
 metrics=['accuracy'])
    entrenando = model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=50,
 validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
resultado = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are using a numpy datetime dtype array as input which is not accepted. Try to convert you datetime array by `new_array = ARRAYNAME.astype('f8')` for example to convert it to floats.